# Как из html извлечь нужный div

Tags: php, html, парсер

Помогите разобраться как на PHP (на стороне сервера без javascript) из html извлечь нужный div из кучи других дивов. Начало могу найти, а закрывающий тег  никак не получается.
нужен `<div class="y1">` внутри него и снаружи тоже куча divов.
Пример html:

```
....
<div class="x1">
   ....
    <div class="y1">
      <div class="x2">
      ....
      </div>
    </div>
   ....
</div>
.....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для работы с `html` используй [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php) и [`DomXPath`](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domxpath.php). Чтобы достать элемент по классу, можно использовать следующий код:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->load($filePath);
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname="y1";
$div = $finder->query(".//div[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
```

Предлагаю почитать про [`XPath`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp), раз собираетесь работать из `php` с `html` документами.

Comment: спасибо, пошел изучать)